# How to disable RadListbox [Telerik] control TransferAll button if list item count is more than 25

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-radlistbox

Not able to enable/disable Transferall button of RadListbox Control [Telerik]. Kindly suggest how to control TransferAll button properties from serverside/client side if list item count is more than some value.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in your function to explicitly bind the datasource to the listbox.

```
if (count > 25)
{
    listbox.ButtonSettings.ShowTransferAll = false;
}
```

Comment: The OP's question is how to DISABLE the button. Your answer looks like to HIDE the button.